# Ansible SSH error although standard ssh is working

Tags: ansible

I want to apply the playbook to the localhost

```
ansible-playbook site.yml --limit localhost -vvvv
```

and I get

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 -tt 127.0.0.1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1456926531.44-231334347877988 `" && echo "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1456926531.44-231334347877988 `"'"'"''
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpBYEsRj TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1456926531.44-231334347877988/setup
<127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10 '[127.0.0.1]'
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable": true}
```

If I run `ssh localhost` it's working. Configuration:

```
$ cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
hostfile = hosts
remote_user = root
host_key_checking = False

[ssh_connection]
control_path = /tmp
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no
```

Comment: I actually used `-vvvv`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the connection to `local` for localhost.

Create a file `host_vars/localhost` relative to your playbook with following content:

```
---

ansible_connection: local

...
```

Alternatively you could call ansible-playbook with the `--connection=local` option but it's good to have the above file in place in case you want to delegate a task to localhost.

Comment: While I'd agree that, normally, you do want to use the local connection type for localhost, it appears that the OP specifically wants to use SSH. And the issue they're having with SSH is weird enough that they'll probably run into it again when trying to access another machine, so it's still worth figuring out and fixing.

Comment: To me it appears the OP instead did simply not know about connection types for three reasons. a) If his intention was to explicitly not use `connection: local` I would expected him to state this in the question. b) I can not see a reason why one explicitly did not want to use local connection when talking to localhost. Again, I would have expected the reasoning for this in the question if this was the case. c) The only mentioned goal was to "apply a playbook to localhost"

Comment: Still if that's the case I would start looking into sshd configuration and check if sftp subsystem is enabled. The verbose output looks like the ssh connection is working but the sftp upload of a module is throwing the error.

Comment: You are right @udondan, I didn't know/remember about connection types, so your answer fixed my problem. However it would be interesting to find out why using SSH didn't work. `$ grep sftp /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

Comment: It works for me.